# Visual Studio Stops Running My Code, and points at a Line (that has no errors)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I run my console program, it stops on the line depicted in the screenshot, and points a little arrow at it.
Here is the line
[image: Here is the line]

Details: I have tried to run the program without it, to see if it is the definitely the source of the problem, but it still stops running, and points that arrow shown in the screenshot at the NEXT line. If I continue commenting out everything the arrow points at, I eventually reach the curly bracket at the end of the method, which the arrow then points at... I don't even know what it's supposed to mean.

Any help to fix this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The red circle to the left indicates that you have a breakpoint set on this line. So, if you run your program in the debugger, the debugger will pause the program when it hits/reaches a code line with a breakpoint. It is probably a good idea if you would spend some time learning the basics about the debugger in Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the red circle in left side of your code to remove it, then start your program again! It’s gone :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Press *F5* to run the whole code or *F10* to run the code line for line
It stops bcs you set a breakpoint in line **132**, like elgonzo commented you already.
Press again *F9* in line **132** to remove the breakpoint, or just click on the *red dot/circle* while ur code is *NOT* running.

Youtube also has a lot of awesome tutorials or read a C# book.